# Sewing lines orders assignment

Tags: optimization

What are the algorithms used to assign orders to sewing lines based on order priority, line capacity, time taken to sew garments, due dates, specialization  of lines etc.

Comment: Welcome to OR.SE. Would you elaborate more on the details you are looking for? Do you look e.g. optimizing required materials? Do you need optimizing the detailed schedule known as resource scheduling? Each of these usually needs its special way to optimize that.

Comment: I want to know about what are the algorithms used to assign sewing orders to sewing lines. Considering constraints like Order due dates, line capacity, time taken for sewing orders, line specialization etc.

Comment: Besides the following answers, this [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/scheduling-of-luxury-goods-final-assembly-lines-with-python-e5c4b0590bfc) may be near to what you are looking for.

Comment: Possibly dupe: [Algorithms to use for an assignment problem](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/11292/491)

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of scheduling problem. Depending on the exact problem, the characteristics of the inputs, and the reason of the resolution, many and different optimization methods might be relevant.

A good starting point is:

- Scheduling (Pinedo, 2015) [DOI](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-26580-3)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a j[ob shop scheduling problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job-shop_scheduling). It is most commonly formulated as either a mixed integer linear program (MILP) or a constraint programming (CP) problem. You can attempt to solve a MILP formulation using pretty much any integer programming solver. For a CP formulation, you will want a solver that supports scheduling-related global constraints, such as no-overlap constraints and precedence constraints.